# rails callback not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I am trying to do an after_save conditional callback

```
after_save :change_rel_status, :if => :relation_type_id == 1

def change_rel_status
  self.status = "Confirmed"
  self.save
end
```

But I get the error message `undefined method after_save for false:FalseClass`

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"_method"=>"put",
"authenticity_token"=>"f4IN...=",
"relationship"=>{"relation_type_id"=>"1",
"category_ids"=>[""]},
"commit"=>"Update Relationship",
"id"=>"19"}
```

I am not sure if it's because the form also has other attributes from other models that were not updated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest something simpler:

```
before_save :change_rel_status

def change_rel_status
  if params[:relationship][:relation_type_id] == 1
    self.status = "Confirmed"
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks but that returns the error msg `stack level too deep`.  I thought it would be better to put the condition on the callback itself so it won't do the callback every time?

Comment: Oh my bad! after_save will trigger change_rel_status which will call save which will get into an infinite loop. Well, either way, it has to check if the condition is fulfilled (namely whether relation_type_id == 1), so I don't see how it's any different.